# Добавить страницу на стек из страницы в отдельном файле QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

У меня задуманна куча переходов по страничкам и все переходы зависят от состояния предыдущей страницы

Загружаюсь с main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {
    StackView {
        id: mainStack
        initialItem: "page0.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

На первой странице просто заглушка

```
Page {
    Image {}
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            mainStack.push("Page1.qml") // не видит объект mainStack
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне протащить mainStack на все страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
ApplicationWindow {

    Component.onCompleted: {
        mainStack.push("page0.qml", {mainStack: mainStack});
    }
    StackView {
        id: mainStack
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Но на 5ом шаге понадобится приостановить таймер живущий на главном окне. Как не тащить его через все страницы, в которых он не нужен?

Можно получить ссылку на стэк из дочерней страницы без передачи аргумента

```
Page {
    property StackView mainStack: StackView.view
}
```